# Don't remember of free Active Directory from Microsoft

Tags: active-directory

I can't remember the name of free AD product from Microsoft even by searching the internet. So what is it?

Answer (score 9):

With the purchase of 1 genuine Windows Server 2008 license you get:

Free Active Directory Services!

Free File and Print services! Now with more printer drivers!

Free Web services! Be the first on your block to have your own web site!

Free DNS service! Goes better together with included free DHCP service.

And much, much more! Don't delay, act now!

No batteries needed.

(Installation and configuration not included).

Comment: Not what I want :) But hey I remember it's ADAM

Comment: ADAM isn't a fully fleged Active Directory though, just Active Directory Application Mode. It's also been renamed to AD LDS in Server 2008.

Comment: "With the purchase of", "Free....", Looks like there is a bug, it's not free if you have to purchase it :)